# Find package name of Android app by uid without root permissions

Tags: android, adb, app-id, package-name

I have a problem of an app that open a site every time open the browser.
I found the id of the app with this intent by adb and now I'm wondering if there is a way to find the package name by the app id without root permissions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> For UnRooted devices following works for me:

Set up `adb` in a PC, connect the device to the PC, launch a `shell` on the PC and enter:

```
adb shell "dumpsys package | grep -A1 'userId=UID'"
```

Replace `UID` with the `ID` you're looking for, such as `10102`.

Example:

```
bash-4.2# adb shell "dumpsys package | grep -A1 'userId=10102'"
   userId=10102
   pkg=Package{46171ce com.android.chrome}
bash-4.2#
```

The line containing Package`{would show the package name of the app in between whitespace and}`. You can do adb shell dumpsys package `PKG_NAME (PKG_NAME → package name of an app)` to know more details about that package/app.

Comment: Might have to do -A2 in grep, if it's a shared uid e.g. for uid 1000.